# Input value received on props doesn't change

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-props

There is an input form:

```
<input type="number" value={propsValue} onChange={changeValue} />
```

`propsValue` is received in the component via props. How should the function `changeValue` to look like in order to be able to change the value in the input form?

Comment: Are you using a functional component, or a class component?

Comment: @JamesHamann a functional component

Comment: you can refer to this https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-forms-tutorial/#2-form-state. but in your case, set the propsValue as the default state value

Answer (score 1):

Edit: realized that I copy pasted a hard codes import path for utility function. Just replace with your utility function path.

For functional components, it can be useful to use a helper utility function to map your inputs to state. This is a setup I use (it is pretty basic). I have a `useForm.js` file, which exports the `useForm` function:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

export default function useForm(defaults) {
  const [values, setValues] = useState(defaults);

  function updateValue(e) {
    if (e.target.type === 'number') {
      e.target.value = parseInt(e.target.value);
    }
    setValues({ ...values, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  return { values, updateValue };
}
```

Then where I want to use the a form, I can do this:

```
import useForm from '../utils/useForm';

export default function MyComponent(props) {
  const { values, updateValue } = useForm({
    name: props.inputValue1,
    email: props.inputValue2
  });

  return (
    <form>
      <label htmlFor="name">
          Name
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            id="name"
            value={values.name}
            onChange={updateValue}
          />
        </label>
        <label htmlFor="email">
          Email
          <input
            type="email"
            name="email"
            id="email"
            value={values.email}
            onChange={updateValue}
          />
        </label>
    </form>
  )
}
```

So you see I use the helper function to tie the inputs to the state of the component. You need to make sure your input names match the names properties you pass when you call `useForm` in your component file.

By the way credit to Wes Bos for this helpfer function.

Comment: I don't get it where are the props received in the component

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I missed that part. So if you are passing props to your component, then use the value of the props when you call useForm. I will update my answer

Comment: Just change your code to use whatever prop values you want to start the input with, and use a default value for any input that doesn't get passed as a prop

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

```js
// hooks
const {useState} = React;

function Input(props){
 return <input type="number" value={props.value} onChange={() => props.onChange(event)} /> 
};


function App(){
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
  function onChange(event){
    setValue(event.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Value: {value}</p>
      <Input value={value} onChange={onChange}/>
    </div>
  );
};

// Render
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```